# Can I use static keyword in class method? What consequence it has?

Tags: php, oop

```
class Foo {

  private $items;

public function getItems() {
  static $loaded = FALSE;

  if (isset($this->items) && $loaded) {
     return $this->items;
  } else if ($loader = $this->getLoader()) {
    //logic for fetching items from other source;
    $this->loaded = TRUE;
  } else {
    $this->items = array();
  }

  return $this->items;
}

}
```

Is it valid to use static variable or better introduce class property?
Does $loaded isn't shared for every class instance? (as e.g: class static variable)?

Comment: It's valid, and the scope is for that instance/method; but not always obvious

Comment: You should not really ever need to use 'static variables inside methods' as you can just declare them in the class and you have complete control of the 'visibility' of them. This is different from `functions` where a 'static variable' is as specified in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both is possible (using a static *variable* in a method and using a private static *class property*).

### How is a static variable different from a static class property?

1. The static variable is not instantiated before the line `static $loaded = FALSE;` is reached. In the following example, you will get an "Undefined variable: loaded" error when you call getItems() for the first time:

   ```
   function getItems()
   {
       var_dump($loaded);
       static $loaded = 1;
   }
   ```
2. The static variable only exists in the scope of the current function/method, so there is no way to read or write it from another method, not even `getItems` of a child class. In the following example, you will also get an "Undefined variable: loaded" error:

   ```
   class Foo
   {
       public function getItems()
       {
           static $loaded = 1;
       }
   }
   class Bar extends Foo
   {
       public function getItems()
       {
           parent::getItems();
           var_dump($loaded);
       }
   }
   (new Bar)->getItems();
   ```

---

**TL;DR:** It is basically just another local variable, except that it keeps its value in subsequent calls to the same **method** (independent of the object!)

---

Another example to demonstrate that the variable is independent of the actual object:

```
class Foo
{
    public function getItems()
    {
        static $loaded = 1;
        $loaded++;
        var_dump($loaded);
    }
}
$foo1 = new Foo;
$foo2 = new Foo;
$foo1->getItems();
$foo2->getItems();
```

Outputs:

```
int(2)
int(3)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for awesome answer. "independent of the object!" so it means that changing value of $loaded in one object (instance) will change it in other objects (objects getItems() method) ?

Comment: Yes, see last example

Answer (score 1):

Method "getItems()" is a normal method and cannot be called unless the class is created. If the class is created and you call "getItems()" the static variable "$loaded" is set to false and your first if statement always evaluates to false. Since that static is defined in the "getItems()" method there is no other way to check that value.
So basically this is a very bad example on how to use static variables.

I'm sure you know that they retain their value even if the class is destructed but checks like these should be better placed in the __construct method and with the static defined in the class scope. This way you can always verify if the class has been initiated yet even if the class is not created yet or using it to check if its loaded in a different method.

But to answer your question, yes you can. They can even be placed in a normal function.